# Can’t undo more than one operation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsundomanager

When I call undo on the context following deletion of a single object, all works as expected. But if user deletes an object, then deletes another object, undo will work only to restore the second object, no matter how many times user requests undo, as though undoLevels were set to 1. This happens whether undoLevels is at the default of 0 (unlimited) or is explicitly set to 6 as a test.

Furthermore, if a single action deletes multiple objects, calling undo afterward has no effect; none of the objects is restored. I tried explicitly bracketing the deletion loop with begin/endUndoGrouping, to no avail. The undoManager’s groupsByEvent is YES (by default), but it makes no difference whether I call a straight undo or undoNestedGroup.

Is the context somehow being saved after each operation? No, because if I quit and relaunch the app after running these tests, all objects are still present in the database.

What am I missing?

---

OK, you want code. Here’s what I imagine is most relevant:

Context getter:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContextMain {

if (managedObjectContextMain) return managedObjectContextMain;

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinatorMain = [self persistentStoreCoordinatorMain];
if (!coordinatorMain) {
    // present error...
    return nil;
}
managedObjectContextMain = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[managedObjectContextMain setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinatorMain];

// Add undo support. (Default methods don't include this.)
NSUndoManager *undoManager = [[NSUndoManager  alloc] init];
// [undoManager setUndoLevels:6]; // makes no difference
[managedObjectContextMain setUndoManager:undoManager];
[undoManager release];

// ...

return managedObjectContextMain;
}
```

Multiple-object deletion method (called by a button on a modal panel):

```
/* 
NOTE FOR SO: 
SpecialObject has a to-one relationship to Series. 
Series has a to-many relationship to SpecialObject.
The deletion rule for both is Nullify.
Series’ specialObject members need to be kept in a given order. So Series has a transformable attribute, an array of objectIDs, used to prepare a transient attribute, an array of specialObjects, in the same order as their objectIDs.
*/
- (void) deleteMultiple {
Flixen_Foundry_AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *contextMain = [appDelegate managedObjectContextMain];

NSUndoManager *undoMgr = [contextMain undoManager];
[undoMgr beginUndoGrouping];

// Before performing the actual deletion, drop the seln in the locator table.
[appDelegate.objLocatorController.tvObjsFound deselectAll:self];

// Get the indices of the selected objects and enumerate through them.
NSIndexSet *selectedIndices = [appDelegate.objLocatorController.tvObjsFound selectedRowIndexes];
NSUInteger index = [selectedIndices firstIndex];
while (index != NSNotFound) {
    // Get the obj to be deleted and its series.
    SpecialObject *sobj = [appDelegate.objLocatorController.emarrObjsLoaded objectAtIndex:index];       
    Series *series = nil;
    series = sobj.series;
    // Just in case...
    if (!series) {
        printf("\nCESeries' deleteMultiple was called when Locator seln included objs that are not a part of a series. The deletion loop has therefore aborted.");
        break;
    }
    // Get the obj's series index and delete it from the series.
    // (Series has its own method that takes care of both relnshp and cache.)
    NSUInteger uiIndexInSeries = [series getSeriesIndexOfObj:sobj];
    [series deleteObj:sobj fromSeriesIndex:uiIndexInSeries];
    // Mark the special object for Core Data deletion; it will still be a non-null object in emarrObjsLoaded (objLocatorController’s cache).
    [contextMain deleteObject:sobj];
    // Get the next index in the set.
    index = [selectedIndices indexGreaterThanIndex:index];
}

[undoMgr endUndoGrouping];

// Purge the deleted objs from loaded, which will also reload table data.
[appDelegate.objLocatorController purgeDeletedObjsFromLoaded];
// Locator table data source has changed, so reload. But end with no selection. (SeriesBox label will have been cleared when Locator seln was dropped.)
[appDelegate.objLocatorController.tvObjsFound reloadData];

// Close the confirm panel and stop its modal session.
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] stopModal];
[self.panelForInput close];
}
```

Here’s the Series method that removes the object from its relationship and ordered cache:

```
/**
Removes a special object from the index sent in.
(The obj is removed from objMembers relationship and from the transient ordered obj cache, but it is NOT removed from the transformable array of objectIDrepns.)
*/
- (void) deleteObj:(SpecialObject *)sobj fromSeriesIndex:(NSUInteger)uiIndexForDeletion {
// Don't proceed if the obj is null or the series index is invalid.
if (!sobj)
    return;
if (uiIndexForDeletion >= [self.emarrObjs count]) 
    return;

// Use the safe Core Data method for removing the obj from the relationship set.
// (To keep it private, it has not been declared in h file. PerformSelector syntax here prevents compiler warning.)
[self performSelector:@selector(removeObjMembersObject:) withObject:sobj];
// Remove the obj from the transient ordered cache at the index given.
[self.emarrObjs removeObjectAtIndex:uiIndexForDeletion];

// But do NOT remove the obj’s objectID from the transformable dataObjIDsOrdered array. That doesn't happen until contextSave. In the meantime, undo/cancel can use dataObjIDsOrdered to restore this obj.
}
```

Here’s the method, and its follow-up, called by comm-z undo:

```
- (void) undoLastChange {
Flixen_Foundry_AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *contextMain = [appDelegate managedObjectContextMain];

// Perform the undo. (Core Data has integrated this functionality so that you can call undo directly on the context, as long as it has been assigned an undo manager.)
//  [contextMain undo]; 
printf("\ncalling undo, with %lu levels.", [contextMain.undoManager levelsOfUndo]);
[contextMain.undoManager undoNestedGroup]; 

// Do cleanup.
[self cleanupFllwgUndoRedo];
}


- (void) cleanupFllwgUndoRedo {
Flixen_Foundry_AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *contextMain = [appDelegate managedObjectContextMain];
DataSourceCoordinator *dataSrc = appDelegate.dataSourceCoordinator;

// ... 

// Rebuild caches of special managed objects.
// (Some managed objects have their own caches, i.e. Series' emarrObjs. These need to be refreshed if their membership has changed. There's no need to use special trackers; the context keeps track of these.)
for (NSManagedObject *obj in [contextMain updatedObjects]) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[Series class]] && ![obj isDeleted])
        [((Series *)obj) rebuildSeriesCaches];
}

// ...

// Regenerate locator's caches.
[appDelegate.objLocatorController regenerateObjCachesFromMuddies]; // also reloads table

}
```

Here’s the series method that regenerates its caches following undo/awake:

```
- (void) rebuildSeriesCaches {  

// Don't proceed if there are no stored IDs.
if (!self.dataObjIDsOrdered || [self.dataObjIDsOrdered count] < 1) {    
    // printf to alert me, because this shouldn’t happen (and so far it doesn’t)
    return;
}

NSMutableArray *imarrRefreshedObjIdsOrdered = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.objMembers count]];
NSMutableArray *emarrRefreshedObjs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.objMembers count]];

// Loop through objectIDs (their URIRepns) that were stored in transformable dataObjIDsOrdered.
for (NSURL *objectIDurl in self.dataObjIDsOrdered) {
    // For each objectID repn, loop through the objMembers relationship, looking for a match.
    for (SpecialObject *sobj in self.objMembers) {
        // When a match is found, add the objectID repn and its obj to their respective replacement arrays.
        if ([[sobj.objectID URIRepresentation] isEqualTo:objectIDurl]) {
            [imarrRefreshedObjIdsOrdered addObject:objectIDurl];
            [emarrRefreshedObjs addObject:sobj];
            break;
        }
        // If no match is found, the obj must have been deleted; the objectID repn doesn't get added to the replacement array, so it is effectively dropped.
    }
}

// Assign their replacement arrays to the transformable and transient attrs.
self.dataObjIDsOrdered = imarrRefreshedObjIdsOrdered;
self.emarrObjs = emarrRefreshedObjs;

}
```

(I’ve omitted the Locator’s regenerateObjCachesFromMuddies because, although I am using its table to view the results of the deletion and undo, I can reload the table with a new fetch, completely regenerating the table’s caches, and this test still shows that the undo isn’t working.)

As usual, just the task of putting together a SO question helps solve the problem, and I realize now that undo works fine as long as I’m working with simple objects that don’t involve the reciprocal SpecialObject-Series relationship. I’m doing something wrong there...

Comment: Post your code. We don't have a crystal ball.

Comment: What are the deletion rules in your Managed Object Model for the SpecialObject and Series relationship (including inverse)?

Comment: @Joshua Nozzi: The rule for both reciprocal relationships is Nullify.

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure I understand your reason for the -undoLastChange method. A grouped undo should be popped all at once. I don't currently see the justification for it and can see a few gotcha's with it. I think, frankly, you're abusing the undo/redo mechanism. :-)

Comment: @Joshua: I thought that, by calling `undoNestedGroup`, I actually *was* popping the grouped undo all at once. I was finally able to get everything to basically work (see addt’l answer below), but I still have some grouping problems, so I’ll need to look at this issue more closely. Anyway, thanks for your input. It helped me get unstuck.

Comment: Thanks for posting your findings. One note: You're not supposed to be calling the undo methods. The system calls them for you. If an undo group is at the top of the stack, it's still one whole "undo" action.

Comment: I'm confused. You mean I should use `undo` rather than `undoNestedGroup`? The Undo Architecture doc says "Performing undo and redo is usually as simple as sending undo and redo messages to an NSUndoManager object." How do I get the system to do that for me?

Comment: When the user chooses Undo/Redo from the menu. Your only job is to instruct the undo manager how to undo an action (including grouping some actions together and calling it a single undoable event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you can have Foo creation that involves changing relationships with pre-existing Bars, and custom caches, and NSUndoManager can still handle it all — but with a kink: You have to save the context after each such change; otherwise the undo manager will cease to function.

Since undo can actually reach back to states *before* the save, this is not such a bad thing. It does complicate matters if you want the user to be able to revert to the state when they last *chose* to save, but that can be handled by making a copy of the database whenever the user chooses to save.

So in the `deleteMultiple` method, following the `while` deletion loop, I added a call to save the context.

There’s another error in my scheme, which is that I erroneously thought NSUndoManager would ignore transformable attributes. Well, obviously, since transformable attrs are persisted, they are tracked by the persistentStoreCoordinator and are therefore included in undo operations. So when I failed to update the xformable attr array upon deletion, thinking I would need its info for restoration in the event of undo, I was ruining the action/inverse-action symmetry.

So in the `deleteObject:fromSeriesIndex` method, the Series method that handles the caches, I added this code, updating the transformable ObjectID array:

```
NSMutableArray *emarrRemoveID = [self.dataObjIDsOrdered mutableCopy];
[emarrRemoveID removeObjectAtIndex:uiIndexForDeletion];
self.dataObjIDsOrdered = emarrRemoveID;
[emarrRemoveID release];
```

(My assumption that the NSUndoManager would ignore the *transient* cache was correct. The call to `rebuildSeriesCaches` in `cleanupFllwgUndoRedo` takes care of that.)

Undo now works, both for simple objects and for objects in SpecialObject-Series relationships. The only remaining problem is that it takes more than one command-Z to happen. I’ll have to experiment more with the groupings…

---

EDIT: It isn’t necessary to save the context post-deletion if the managed object’s custom caches are handled correctly:

1) The caches should NOT be rebuilt following undo. The undo manager will take care of this on its own, even for the transient cache, as long as the transient property is included in the managed object model.

2) When changing the NSMutableArray cache (`emarrObjs`), using removeObjectAtIndex alone will confuse the undo manager. The *entire* cache must be replaced, the same way it is with the NSArray cache `dataObjIDsOrdered`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting into a fight with custom undo stuff and Core Data's automagic support.

In normal undo/redo code, you have undoable funnel points. Usually an undoable add and its inverse undoable remove. Calling one registers the other as the inverse action and vice-versa. User undo/redo then just goes back and forth between them. You separate your "user created a new Foo" code from your "now add this foo to the collection undoably" code (that way "remove Foo" and "add Foo" work independently of supplying a newly-created Foo).

With Core Data, add and remove means "insert into the context and remove from the context". Also, you still need custom funnel methods because (in your case), you're doing some additional stuff (updating a cache). This is easy enough to do with a Foo, but what happens when you want to manipulate the relationship between a Foo/Bar assembly that gets created in one action?

If creating a Foo created a few Bars with it, it'd be one thing (-awakeFromInsert and the like) since you'd only have to deal with updating your caching (which you *could* do, by the way, through key/value observing the context for changes). Since creating a Foo seems to establish relationships with existing Bars (which are already in the context), you run into a difficult wall when trying to cooperate with CD's built-in undo support.

There is *no easy solution* in this case if you're using the built-in Core Data undo/redo support. In this case, you can [do as this post suggests](http://www.mikeabdullah.net/core_data_undo_management.html) and turn it off. You can then handle undo/redo entirely yourself ... but you'll have a lot of code to write to observe your objects for changes to interesting attributes, registering the inverse action for each.

While it isn't a solution to your problem, I hope it at least points out the complexity of what you're trying to do and gives you a possible path forward. Without knowing a LOT more about your model (at the conceptual level at least) and how your UI presents it to the user, it's hard to give specific architectural advice.

I hope I'm wrong about this case - maybe someone else can give you a better answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look through all that. Your mention of Foo creation involving changing relationships with pre-existing Bars gives me a bead on the problem. Maybe I can constrain how I allow the user to create and change Foo. Abdullah's blog is also very helpful. But, yeeah, this does look like a mess. Well, I've got to do some thinking...